# Is it possible to generate a gradient from color swatches?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, gradient, swatches

I am trying to generate two gradients using color swatches in Adobe Illustrator. It took me a very long time to find out that it's possible to save the colors using "Add Used Colors", and as it can generate the swatches automatically, I was wondering: is it possible to generate a range of colors from the swatches?

I mean - is it possible to pick one color from the swatches menu, and another one, and using them generate a long gradient (including any color that is between the two)?

I already saved the range of colors that I want, but if there is any way to make my life easier and generate the gradient without really picking every color, it will be awesome.

Comment: Technically there could be millions of colors between them, how many colors are you talking about? (how much variation do they need to have)

Comment: @WELZ about 12-13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add colors to a gradient simply by dragging the color swatch onto the gradient palette, on the gradient line.

If you want to remove a color from a gradient, drag it down from the gradient line.

Once your gradient is done, you can drag it from the gradient palette back into the color swatch palette to create a new swatch with the gradient.

Comment: So my answer is valid; with 2 colors the steps in between will be automatically generated. If you want to add steps in between, you can add more colors to the gradient, for example to create a rainbow colored gradient.

Comment: Can I drag a color group to the gradient too?

Comment: Unfortunately not... only one color at a time. I just tried with with groups as well as by selecting multiple colors.

Comment: Well, I'll do it manually. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 4):

Apply your gradient to a shape (using the 2 colors)

[image]

Now go to *Object → Expand* and set it to the amount of colors you want (I did 15)

[image]

*Right click → Ungroup and Right Click → Release clipping mask*

Now click the new folder Icon in swatches panel (Window → Swatches) and make sure to select "from artwork"  and it will make a folder of swatches using the colors from your gradient. (you will have chosen earlier exactly how many)

[image]

Comment: You learn something new every day. The option is buggy in my CS6, though: when I tell it to do a certain number, it apparently divides that number by ~4. Ah well.

Comment: Thanks but this is similar to what @Vincent suggested and this isn't what i'm looking for. I try to create a gradient from a color group

Comment: @Vincent for me it sorta averages it out (ends up doing a few less than I chose)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a script that does that:

[**Illy Grad:** Create gradient from selected swatches in Adobe Illustrator.](https://github.com/mhulse/illy-grad)

[image]

Works in CC 2019 and not in 2020.

Answer (score 0):

1. Draw to objects with a fill, some distance apart;
2. Make the fill colours of the two objects the two colours you want to know the intermediaires of;
3. Select both of them;
4. Choose the <kbd>Blend</kbd> tool (<kbd>W</kbd>);
5. Click an anchor on one of the shapes;
6. Click the corresponding anchor on the other shape;
7. <kbd>Double click</kbd> the Blend tool in the toolbox to change the blend's settings and change them to 'Smooth Color' if necessary. If it's a determined amount of intermediaries you're looking for, enter that number under the option 'Specified Steps';
8. <kbd>Object > Expand</kbd> the blend and <kbd>Object > Ungroup</kbd> if desired.

The resulting shapes will have all intermediate colours, which you can eyedrop and store in your Swatches palette at leisure.

Comment: This is great for the next time (I already saved each color) but it's not what i'm looking for. Thank you for this great solution :)

Comment: Gradient from swatch, not the other way around.

Comment: @Webster That has been clarified in the meantime. The question was not particularly clear in its initial formulation. I left my answer because it may be useful nonetheless. I sincerely do *not* appreciate your comment, which I read as very smug.

Comment: Oh, sorry Vincent. I just wanted to explain the problem with few words.

Comment: @Webster Thanks, sorry for sounding grumpy :)